# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended EVEN tho I am actually using the standard syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax-error, oracle-apex

I am working on a project for my SQL class and after making a query with subqueries in it i received this error:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Automatically I started looking for answers everywhere and after a lot  of searching, I thought it would be easier to remake the query step by step, and after butchering it I remained with the error and now it looks like this:

> Error at line 3/16: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Query:

```
UPDATE requests
SET price = 3
WHERE price= 10;

ROLLBACK;
```

I simplified it as much as I could but it looks like it stuck with me even if the query is as simple as that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your code works [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SkxghRyD). What client are you using to run the code and how are you running the code in that client?

Comment: At the moment I'm using Oracle Apex, but after some more digging, it seems that it has to have a problem with ending my sequence with ROLLBACK. The problem is I have to get back after entering my query.

Comment: Are you submitting that as a PL/SQL block? Or does Apex automatically add such a wrapper or interpret that and automatically break those up into two separate database calls? Either way, it'll be an Apex question. It's not a problem with `ROLLBACK` but with how two different SQL statements are being submitted together.

Comment: Thanks for your time guys, I just posted the solution. Tbh, I feel a bit dumb for going as far as posting it here. As I said, I think Apex is just a bit sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found one way to make it work - use PL/SQL block.

Error you got is due to Apex running *everything* it finds at once (it isn't related to `rollback`, could've been any other statement - select, update, delete, create table, ... whatever).

[image]

However, if you first **select** a single statement and then click the "Run" button, it'll work:

[image]

---

Yet another way to execute statements is to create a **script** and run that script:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I found the solution. It actually has something to do with the rollback syntax. The code should look like this:

```
  BEGIN   
    UPDATE requests
    SET price = 3
    WHERE price= 10;
    ROLLBACK;
 END;
```

The update sequence was ok, probably my client is a bit sensitive and can't get a point in time to rollback to so I actually need to tell him I start a new transaction.

Comment: No, this doesn't tell the DBMS to do this in one transaction instead of two. It tells the DBMS that it shall execute one PL/SQL block instead of an SQL statement. The difference: In a PL/SQL block you can wrap several SQL statements. In a SQL statement there can only be one command, but `UPDATE` and `ROLLBACK` are two.

Comment: Oh, thank you for further clarification, now it's clear why it was happening and why that's what it fixed it.